# C++: Need More Help on Streams

Tags: c++, stream

I have been reading about streams, but when I try and deviate from the books to accomplish a task I seem to be doing something wrong. Anyways here is the start of my code. If this code can work with slight modifications please let me know, else if you could provide a better "more C++ like" route I would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::multimap<std::string,float> _map;

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> in ) { 
    return stream >> in.first >> in.second;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) { 
    istream is( );
    do {
        pair<string,float> input;
        is >> input;
        _map.insert(input);
    } while( is );
}
```

Compiler errors are:

```
[mehoggan@desktop bjarne_stroustrup]$ g++ -o map -Wall ./key_value_stats.cpp
./key_value_stats.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
./key_value_stats.cpp:20:15: error: no match for ‘operator>>’ in ‘is >> input’
./key_value_stats.cpp:12:10: note: candidate is: std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, float>)
./key_value_stats.cpp:22:14: warning: the address of ‘std::istream is()’ will always evaluate as ‘true’
```

---

UPDATE[0]:

After removing the ( ) 
and changing:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> in ) {
```

to

```
istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> &in ) {
```

I get a different set of compiler errors:

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/istream: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.5.1/../../../../include/c++/4.5.1/istream:582:7: error: ‘std::basic_istream<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_istream() [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]’ is protected
./key_value_stats.cpp:17:13: error: within this context
```

with the following code:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::multimap<std::string,float> _map;

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> &in ) {
    return stream >> in.first >> in.second;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) { 
    istream is;
    do {
        pair<string,float> input;
        is >> input;
        _map.insert(input);
    } while( is );
}
```

---

UPDATE[1]

Okay I solved the issue I think. Going back to Stroustrup's desk_calculator example, I have the following code which at least compiles, I will add the final features into it, and then re-post the final product for anyone interested.

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::multimap<std::string,float> _map;

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> &in ) {
    return stream >> in.first >> in.second;
}

//void print_pair( pair<string,float>

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) { 
    istream *is = &cin;
    do {
        pair<string,float> input;
        (*is) >> input;
        _map.insert(input);
    } while( is );
}
```

---

UPDATE[2]

I don't think I met the requirements of the problem but I got the technical stuff to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

/********************************************************************
 * Read a sequence of possibly whitespace-separated (name,value)
 * pairs, where the name is a single whitespaace-separated word and
 * the value is an integer or floating-point value. Compute and print
 * the sum and mean for each name and the sum and mean for all names
 * ******************************************************************/

using namespace std;

std::multimap<string,float> _map;

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float> &in ) {
    return stream >> in.first >> in.second;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, pair<string,float> &out ) {
    return stream << "(" << out.first 
                  << ", " << out.second << ")" << endl;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) { 
    istream *is = &cin;
    do {
        pair<string,float> input;
        (*is) >> input;
        _map.insert(input);
    } while( is->peek( ) != EOF );

    ostream *os = &cout;
    multimap<string,float>::iterator mit = _map.begin( );
    float sum = 0.0;
    while( mit != _map.end( ) ) {
        pair<string,float> p_pair = (*mit);
        (*os) << p_pair;
        sum+=p_pair.second;
        mit++;
    }
    float mean = static_cast<float>( sum/_map.size( ) );
    (*os) << "Sum: " << sum << " Mean: " << mean << endl;
}
```

Comment: Using a reference for your istream would remove the dereferencing operator inside your loop, or just use cin directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

std::multimap<std::string,float> _map;

istream& operator>>(istream& stream, pair<string,float>& in ) { 
    return stream >> in.first >> in.second;
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[ ] ) { 
    do {
        pair<string,float> input;
         cin >> input;
        _map.insert(input);
    } while( cin );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the () from the line:

```
istream is();
```

Should be:

```
istream is;
```

Or:

```
istream is("text 1.2");
```

Or else **is** is a function that returns an istream.

Comment: And search for C++'s most vexing parse to understand why `istream is();` is not what you expect.

Comment: Good catch, even when you know what the most vexing parse is, I find it hard to spot.

Comment: You can't construct an `std::istream` with either of the proposed alternatives though. You'll probably want an `std::ifstream` or `std::istringstream`.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker, this also fixes the compilation error as far as I can tell.

Comment: @daramarak : it fixes the original compilation error, but you'll be presented with a new one (as @Matthew Hoggan found out in the meantime). There is no (exposed) default constructor for `std::istream`.

Comment: @Sander De Dycker I meant that using a istringstream like you mention will fix the final compilation problem. (Which was why I upvoted your comment)

Comment: @daramarak : sorry - I misunderstood.